# How to decrypt large files in chunks?

Tags: python, encryption, pgp

I am trying to decrypt a large file with PgPy and had this problem:

```
OverflowError: integer 2632261350 does not fit '32-bit int'
```

Clearly the size of the file is not suitable, so I would like to know how I can decrypt large files in chunks? we can decrypt blocks of data? or we can only decrypt the whole data with the key that we have?

Comment: It would be weird if the data was divided up into chunks, at least from my understanding of crytology is that any time you alter the original data (dividing it into chunks) the encryption/raw-data will be easier to guess/reverse. And some crypto's rely on previous data when encrypting and in those cases it would have to start over on each block. I'm no expert, but I'd say you have to decrypt the whole data as it's one entity. I might be wrong in pgp specifics tho.

Comment: I agree but seems we are wrong with our knowledge.. i just saw this blog, he is decrypting/encrypting in chunks with other library but as a concept he is doing it and is making it work

https://medium.com/@ismailakkila/black-hat-python-encrypt-and-decrypt-with-rsa-cryptography-bd6df84d65bc

Comment: I'll try his way and if it works imma post it as an answer

Comment: That's because the file itself is **encrypted using chunks**, aka the whole data isn't encrypted in one go - but rather individual chunks. Which leads me back to the original statement, if you chunk the data - it will be easier to guess the key. Imagine you encrypt one byte and pad to the minimum length with zeroes and this is know information. The attacker would only have to guess one byte, aka 255 times with a set of random keys in order to find the key you used. All be it time consuming, that's easier than guessing against 2GB of encrypted data (in simple terms).

Comment: But I should also mention, the key is the most important thing, even if encrypting one byte, the key size used to encrypt the data and the method are the most important parts. This is btw how most modern chat applications use p2p encryption. They chunk the data pre-encryption and sends it in chunks/pages. But this is a design choice, not a problem with PgPy or any other library :)

Comment: I will try decrypting in streams .. what do you think?

Comment: My opinion doesn't matter, try it out and see if it fits your needs. Encryption shouldn't be, but it's all about risk vs usability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about pgpy but have a lookt at [python-gnupg](https://docs.red-dove.com/python-gnupg/). It is a wrapper for gnupg that is able to encrypt/decrypt files as a stream.

```py
with stream as open(filename,"rb"):
    decrypted_data = gpg.decrypt_file(stream) # e.g. after stream = open(filename, "rb")
```

I believe it is more a memory issue than a library issue. If you can decrypt as a stream with pgpy, you would obtain the same result.